# JS effect util page is loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make a fully white background with a loading bar or something util videos/image/scripts are fully loaded. And after loading I want to put an FadeIn effect from animate.css to all body elemnts.

I want a loading page script like [this](http://themeforest.net/item/besmart-education-courses-html-template/full_screen_preview/11441827)

Comment: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/08/05/page-preloading-effect/ A quick google search will get you a long way

Comment: I search man... thanks anyway.

Comment: you can find loaders here http://codepen.io/collection/HtAne/ -- as for the content usual you use ajax to load the page which tells you when the function completes so you can remove the loader and fade in the page. if you have images too then you can use an image preloader function to let you know when those have finished loading too. or you can use a plugging -- https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded

Answer (score 1):

Simplest algorithm for your case. Let's say you have this HTML.

```
<body>
    <div class="preloader">
        <span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper initial">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

**1)** Put such CSS style in your style sheet

```
.wrapper {
    text-align:center;
    padding:50px;
}

.initial {
    display:none;
}

.preloader {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.preloader span {
    display:block;
    margin : 70px auto;
    width : 100px;
    height : 100px;
    background : url('http://www.firstimpressionsdentistry.com/images/animated_preloader.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat;
}
```

**2)** Add JS file with such content, for simplicity I will use JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //display(); // uncomment this if you want to display immediately

    setTimeout(function() {
        display();  // example with custom delay
    }, 5000)
})

function display() {

    var wrapper = $('.initial');
    var loader = $('.preloader');

    loader.fadeOut(2000);

    wrapper.fadeIn(4000, function() {
        wrapper.removeClass('initial');
    });
}
```

Comment: And if page is loading to fast? Can add 2-3 duration seconds?